# Airflow flower pod restarting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-2.x, flower

I am installing airflow 2.4.3 on GCP. The pod airflow flower keep getting restarted.

Below is the snapshot of the logs:-

```
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.1.2 -> 22.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:1379: DeprecationWarning: Specifying both AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and airflow_home in the config file is deprecated. Please use only the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and remove the config file entry.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545: DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545: DeprecationWarning: The logging_level option in [core] has been moved to the logging_level option in [logging] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545 DeprecationWarning: The base_log_folder option in [core] has been moved to the base_log_folder option in [logging] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545 DeprecationWarning: The dag_processor_manager_log_location option in [core] has been moved to the dag_processor_manager_log_location option in [logging] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
[2022-12-22 05:25:33,452] {{settings.py:266}} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 1)
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545 DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_pool_size option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_pool_size option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
[2022-12-22 05:25:33,454] {{settings.py:377}} DEBUG - settings.prepare_engine_args(): Using pool settings. pool_size=1000, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=1
[2022-12-22 05:25:34,457] {{cli_action_loggers.py:39}} DEBUG - Adding <function default_action_log at 0x7f8dd5a2d9e0> to pre execution callback
```

Although I have moved sql_alchemy_pool_size to [database] and base_log_folder to [logging] I am still getting these warnings in airflow flower logs.

Please help me with finding the root cause of this pod restart, and how I can prevent this.

Let me know if any further logs/info ( config ) is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to low resources, after setting the CPU to 500m and memory to 512m, the pod is working fine.